# Wrong function key layout on a Mid 2011 MacBook Air

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

My wife just got a used Mid 2011 MacBook Air. The keyboard looks like this:
[image: Actual keyboard]

But the keys work like this:

[image: Works like this]

There's no way no adjust the backlight brightness and the volume controls are all messed up. How can I fix this?

Comment: It probably won't help, but you could try deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and restarting.

Comment: I also have a mid-2011 MacBook Air which has recently developed the exact issue you describe. I changed my trackpad about a week ago because the original became so flaky it was not useable. The one I purchased claimed to be for both the 2011 and 2012 Airs. I am going to reinstall the old trackpad to see if it is the cause and will post back.

Answer (score 1):

I am back after reinstalling my old flaky trackpad. My function keys are back to normal. This shows that the trackpad somehow interacts with the keyboard layout but I can not tell you how. Since the mid-2011 Air models seem to have numerous trackpad problems, it is possible your wife's used one had had the trackpad replaced.